# Hide block when entering footer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a block that appears after scrolling 200px on the page

```js
const navShareLink = document.getElementById('navShareLink');
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if(window.scrollY > 200 && window.innerWidth > 576) {
    navShareLink.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    navShareLink.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
.article-wrapper {
  min-height: 200vh;
}
.article-wrapper p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

footer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.sidemenu-shares {
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  gap: 40px;
}

.rectangle {
  z-index: 998;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 106px;
  width: 23px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-wrapper">

<div class="sidemenu-shares">
  <div id="navShareLink" class="rectangle">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-banner">
<h1>Title</h1>
</div>

<div>Main content...</div>
<div>Main content...</div>
<div>Main content...</div>
<div>Main content...</div>
<div>Main content...</div>
<div>Main content...</div>
<div>Main content...</div>
<div>Main content...</div>
<div>Main content...</div>

</div>

<footer>
  Footer...
</footer>
```

But when it reaches the end of the page where the footer is, I need it to hide back so that it does not climb into the footer

It's easy to do if the page has the same height, but for me it can be either 2500px or 5000px

Is it possible to somehow count the pixels in reverse order, but not from the beginning of the page, but let's say 300px from the end?

I tried to get the height of the whole page and subtract 300

I used `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` I thought I would just get a digital value like 4500, but in the end I get the output of this value in a pop-up window when I open the page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTgtI.jpg

Alternatively, i can somehow hide this block when it touches the footer, is it possible to do it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this we need to get appropriate properties from key elements:

- `document.body.scrollHeight` - here html has the scrollbar and body is overflowing. [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) gives height of the entire document with overflow.
- `footer.offsetHeight` - actual height of the footer.
- `wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().y` - this gives y position of wrapper when we scroll down. It's negative cos the wrapper goes up.

Remaining math is simple:

```js
var sideMenu, footer, wrapper, nsl;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

function check() {
  var range = document.body.scrollHeight - footer.offsetHeight;
  var position = (nsl.offsetHeight + nsl.getBoundingClientRect().y - wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().y).toFixed(1);

  nsl.innerText =
    '\n Range: ' + range +
    '\n Position: ' + position;

  if (window.scrollY > 200 && (range > position)) {
    nsl.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    nsl.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
};

function init() {
  sideMenu = document.getElementById('sideMenu');
  footer = document.getElementById('footer');
  wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  nsl = document.getElementById('navShareLink');

  window.onscroll = check;
  check();
}
```

```css
.article-wrapper {
  min-height: 200vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.article-wrapper p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

footer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.sidemenu-shares {
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  gap: 40px;
}

.rectangle {
  z-index: 998;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 106px;
  width: 123px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.content {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="article-wrapper">

  <div id='sideMenu' class="sidemenu-shares">
    <div id="navShareLink" class="rectangle">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-banner">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>

  <div class='content'>Main content...</div>
  <div class='content'>Main content...</div>
  <div class='content'>Main content...</div>
  <div class='content'>Main content...</div>
  <div class='content'>Main content...</div>
  <div class='content'>Main content...</div>
  <div class='content'>Main content...</div>
  <div class='content'>Main content...</div>
  <div class='content'>Main content...</div>
</div>

<footer id='footer'>
  Footer...
</footer>
```

Check the output in full page mode.

Comment: I get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined
    at onload`

Comment: It's running fine on stackoverflow. Have you included the javascript? there is a function in the script `function init() {`

Comment: yes everything is there, I added `onload="init ()"` to the `body`, but the `body` is in a separate `app.blade` file that is applied to all pages, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: ohh remove the space between init and `()` make it `onload='init()'`

Comment: sorry, I don’t have a space there, it was just copied here, the error is the same

Comment: I have no idea about the framework you are using. but instead of adding it on the body tag you can use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false)` I've updated my answer.

Comment: I use laravel, now it seems to work) only now I need my data instead of range + position in this block

Comment: And if, for example, in addition to the `navShareLink` block, I have one more, say `navToTop`, which will be located next, can I use this for two at once? for example like this `document.getElementById('navShareLink', 'navToTop')`

Comment: you'll have to get objects for both separately: `document.getElementById('navShareLink')` and `document.getElementById('navToTop')`; and add their heights to the position rest of the equation remains same.

Comment: Yes, I already did that, but I got a problem when these blocks reach the footer, they hide as they should, and sometimes they just start freezing and stay in place, what could be the problem?

Comment: on top of all pages, everything normally hides, and where the footer is some kind of nonsense (((

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8exmpbhy/  here you can see for yourself to make it clearer what kind of friezes

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3tvb074j/ don't use `display:none` use `visiblity:hidden`. display:none takes element out of layout so their heights stop contributing the equations. Also add 40px gap for each new element.

Comment: Everything works, thank you very much for your help))))

Answer (score 2):

## IntersectionObserver API ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API))

This API allows you to observe elements on your page and invoke code based on their position relative to your current viewport.

Example:

#### 1. The callback

```js
const callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
    //   entry.boundingClientRect
    //   entry.intersectionRatio
    //   entry.intersectionRect
    //   entry.isIntersecting <- This is what you usually look out for
    //   entry.rootBounds
    //   entry.target
    //   entry.time

    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      document.getElementById('navShareLink').style.display = 'none';
  });
};
```

#### 2. Create the observer

```js
const options = {
  root: document.body,

  // This specifies a margin around the target (basically changes the size of the target) - can be negative
  rootMargin: '0px 0px 0px 0px',

  // This specifies how much of the target needs to be in the viewport to qualify as 'intersecting' (1 === 100%)
  threshold: 1.0
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

#### 3. Ovserve an element

```js
const target = document.querySelector('footer');
observer.observe(target);
```

One observer can observe an arbitrary number of targets. It is usually the most performant way to handle this sort of thing.

Scroll Event handlers usually trigger very often and are thus quite inefficient. If you use scroll-handlers you should at the very least [debounce](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/) them.

Comment: Did everything like this, but nothing worked, this element does not hide when it enters the footer

Comment: Check which one is your scrolling element (with the browser dev-tools). It might not be document.body. Set the root to this one (or omit root, it defaults to document)

Comment: sorry, but I don’t understand where to check it

Comment: Then just try omitting the root field :) - Also maybe put a console.log() inside the callback function so you can see the result of the observer!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what you want but just in case you want the sidebar to be sticky and when you go down to the footer it is above that block you have to get the sidebar code out of div class="main-content" like that

```css
/* The important part: */

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  position: sticky;
  top: 8px;
  /* This should match the top margin/padding on the body */
}


/* Cosmetics for the demo: */

.main-content {
  min-height: 200vh;
}

.main-content p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 25vw;
  min-height: 25vh;
  background-color: #a00;
}

footer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--  here sidebar  -->
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar...
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div>Main content...</div>
    <div>Main content...</div>
    <div>Main content...</div>
    <div>Main content...</div>
    <div>Main content...</div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    Footer...
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.article-wrapper {
  min-height: 200vh;
}

.article-wrapper p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

footer {
  min-height: 30px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.sidemenu-shares {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 18vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.rectangle {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="article-wrapper row">

    <div class="sidemenu-shares">
      <div class="rectangle">
        <ul>
          <li>Home </li>
          <li>Contact</li>
          <li>About</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">

      <div class="main-banner">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>Main content...</div>
        <div>Main content...</div>
        <div>Main content...</div>
        <div>Main content...</div>
        <div>Main content...</div>
        <div>Main content...</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <footer>
    Footer...
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Maybe this is the answer that you are looking for but I didn't make the sidebar on top of others instead I inserted the sidebar and main content to a div then I added display flex to make it in a row but if you want still to make the sidebar on the top of others you can just change it's position to absolute ,sticky or fixed then add a margin to the main content and for the footer I used position relative so it won't be affected by the sidebar or you could just set the height of the sidebar

Comment: I need this panel to be of a specific size and move throughout the page to the very footer, without crossing it

Comment: I don't know if it will work but try to set the position of footer to sticky with bottom: 0; property then set its z-index higher to the sidebar

Comment: unfortunately does not help

Comment: see my example below that might be what your lookin for